# propagating select form values throughout DOM based on multiple class names via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

Having a bunch of drop-down lists all sharing the same (several) class attributes I want to propagate their values through the DOM upon change.

```
  <select class='drpdwn required'>(...)</select>
```

So, this works:

```
        $("select").change(function() {
            var newval = $(this).val();
            var the_class = $(this).attr('class');
            var ar = the_class.split(" ");
            the_class = ar[0];
            $("."+the_class).val(newval);
        });
```

But it also changes

```
  <select class='drpdwn not_required'>(...)</select>
```

And this doesn't propagate:

```
        $("select").change(function() {
            var newval = $(this).val();
            var the_class = $(this).attr('class');
            $("."+the_class).val(newval);
        });
```

What am I missing? Can I not select an element via jQuery like this?

```
  $('.three class names')
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean `$('.three .class .names')`, unless those should be elements.

Comment: there is no `<input type="select" />`, make sure you are selecting the correct elements

Comment: if you want to exclude some class, you can use  `$("input[type=select]:not(.CLASS_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_EXCLUDE)")`

Comment: @remyabel Yes, thank you!!! That's also what is causing the issue.

Comment: @jasonslyvia Yes, of course. Changed it.

Thanks, guys.

So the line must be:

the_class = the_class=str.replace(" "," .");